# Append dict to list in Ansible

Tags: python, list, ansible

I'm having a problem when trying to append a dict to a list in Ansible.

My code:

```yaml
- name: Initialize list for numbers
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    numbers: [123, 456, 789]

- name: Initialize list of objects
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    resources: []

- name: Initialize object
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    resource: {}

- name: Creating object for reference
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    resource:
      - projectRef:
          external: 'projects/{{ item }}'
    resources: "{{ resources + [ resource ] }}"
  loop: "{{ numbers }}"
```

And the output looks like so:

```py
[
  {},
  [
    {
      'projectRef': {
        'external': 'projects/123'
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'projectRef': {
        'external': 'projects/456'
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

The first issue is that it omits the first value in the numbers list. Moreover I was expecting the output to be a list of dicts, not a list of lists. More like so:

```py
[
    {
      'projectRef': {
        'external': 'projects/123'
      }
    },
    {
      'projectRef': {
        'external': 'projects/456'
      }
    },
    {
      'projectRef': {
        'external': 'projects/789'
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to declare the list

```yaml
  resources: "{{ ['project']|product(numbers)|map('join', '/')|
                 map('community.general.dict_kv', 'external')|
                 map('community.general.dict_kv', 'projectRef') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  resources:
  - projectRef:
      external: project/123
  - projectRef:
      external: project/456
  - projectRef:
      external: project/789
```

Optionally, you can use Jinja. The below declaration gives the same result

```yaml
  resources: |
    [{% for i in numbers %}
    {"projectRef": {"external": "projects/{{ i }}"}},
    {% endfor %}]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    numbers: [123, 456, 789]
    resource1: "{{ ['project']|product(numbers)|map('join', '/')|
                   map('community.general.dict_kv', 'external')|
                   map('community.general.dict_kv', 'projectRef') }}"
    resource2: |
      [{% for i in numbers %}
      {"projectRef": {"external": "projects/{{ i }}"}},
      {% endfor %}]
    
  tasks:


    - debug:
        var: resource1
    - debug:
        var: resource1.1.projectRef.external

    - debug:
        var: resource2
    - debug:
        var: resource2.1.projectRef.external
```